# PDF viewer prints blank pages

Tags: printing, pdf

I have a computer running Ubuntu 13.04 with a Konica Minolta Bizhub C20 printer that's connected over Ethernet.

When I print a PDF using the built-in PDF viewer in Ubuntu, the page will be blank, even though the PDF looks perfectly okay on the screen. However, if I open the very same file in Firefox instead, I can print it just fine without any problems at all.

What could be causing this problem?

The computer in question was previously running Ubuntu 11.04, and PDFs would always print correctly. I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.04.